# linking models ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models: user, seller and cars

i want the user to be able to choose a car from a seller and this gets added to the user's shopping list.

I have something like this in my car controller:

```
 @user = User.find(params[:user])
  @seller = Seller.find(params[:seller])

  @car = @user.cars.build(params[:car])
```

but the seller isnt being added. how can I do this please?

Btw I have this:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :seller
end
```

in my Model for car

Comment: You have asked 45 questions, but accepted answers on only 4. You might find more people are willing to help if you accept answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add:

`@car.seller = @seller` after you build the car. Then `@car.save`

Build doesn't know about @seller, you need to tell the car that it has a seller. It only really knows that there's a user because you created the car from the user.

You could also do:

```
@car = Car.new
@car.seller = @seller
@car.user = @user
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ensure that the fields in your form that produce params[:car] includes a field for the seller's id you won't need to change your controller at all.

Eg:

```
<% fields_for :car, @seller.cars.build do |car_form| %>
 <%= car_form.hidden_field :seller_id
 ... more fields for car form ...

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@car.seller = @seller
```